# How can I adapt fourthcore to play-by-forum?

Tags: dnd-4e, online-roleplaying, play-by-post, fourthcore

Fourthcore adventures have an ingrained time limit that puts pressure on player action and prompts fast, dashy solutions rather than overcautious approaches (or at least has the players chose which one is less detrimental to them).

Suppose I want to play the fourthcore dungeons over the internet, specifically on a play-by-forum, and I decide that the time limit will change to a certain number of in-game rounds.

Now, I know that not every group moves at the same pace and some tables might be faster than others, yet the fourthcore scenarios give the same amount of play time to everybody. **So, what would be a reliable way to set this timer? How many rounds for, e.g., a three-hour scenario?** Should it vary according to the number of fighting encounters (that tend to consume more time per round)?

This time will probably be changed after some playtesting, but I don't think I will do much myself.

Comment: There is [a paragraph about play-by-post systems on fourthcoreteamdeathmatch.com](http://www.fourthcoreteamdeathmatch.com/p/overview-2.html). Did you already read that?

Comment: That is a great start of an answer, @Philipp. (No I didn't see that, looking at it now.)

Comment: @Philipp the link is gone :(

Comment: [It wasn't very hard to find](https://fourthcoreteamdeathmatch.blogspot.com/p/overview-2.html).

Comment: @Philipp Thanks (for real)! Anyway, the point is, you should really write an answer where you summarize the contents of the link, because links on the internet often rot and then we lose the knowledge we had. If you don't care about writing that answer (and getting the upvotes), tell me and I will answer the question myself.

Comment: I do not feel confident writing an answer because I don't know anything about this system.

Comment: @Philipp ah, I've taken a look at it again and it's for PvP content. :( Sorry for having bothered you.